# iMessage/Chat exit to see new message

Tags: messages, chat

iMessage started acting up today. If I get a message from someone and I am reading it in the "chat" window when that person sends me a new message, I have to click>Messages(1), exit the chat window and click on them again to go back into the chat and see the new message.

It wasn't doing this yesterday.  Yesterday, a new message would just pop up in the "chat" window.  Any ideas why/how to fix?

Comment: This seems to be a hiccup in the beta, there's not much anybody can do. And since it's a beta, it'll probably be fixed by the time it launches officially (if not, then you can ask again here). BTW, try to be a little clearer next time (you don't say which platform -- although we can *guess* it's OS X Lion) and formatting the question wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Sorry about that, its Ios5 on my Iphone 4s.  This was my first time on the board, how do I format the question? What are you looking for there? And thanks for your answer.-Kevin